# Remove default google map tooltips

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

I am using com.google.maps.gwt.client.GoogleMap
and i wonder if it is possible to remove or disable default tooltips on mouse click or on mouseover

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (e) {
    e.mb.target.removeAttribute('title');
}
```